# Java Could not reserve enough space for object heap

Tags: java, windows, bit, minecraft

i have win7 32 bit java and 4 gb ram but still does 
`java -Xmx4G -Xms4G -jar Minecraft.jar` 
`java -Xmx3G -Xms3G -jar Minecraft.jar`
`java -Xmx2G -Xms2G -jar Minecraft.jar`
not work.

error;

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

`java -Xmx1G -Xms1G -jar Minecraft.jar` is work.

Answer (score 3):

`win7 32bit` cannot use `4GB` of memory for a `user program`.

The maximum any user program can use is '3GB' this includes code and data so `-Xmx3G` will cause it to fail everytime as you are giving 3GB to the heap which leaves zero space 
for all the other things the program will need let alone the JVM.

I question the value of setting mx.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum size java can allocate for heap on Windows is about 1.5G because this OS tries to allocate a contiguous chunk of memory. If you need to run java with more heap size, you have to use Linux.

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/04/what-is-maximum-heap-size-for-32-bit-64-JVM-Java-memory